# How to programatically set time of latest full charge on Android?

Tags: android, battery, internals

How, if at all, is it possible to manually alter the timestamp of latest full battery charge a system call on Android? How does the adb command alter the value?

Comment: No. Why should it be (aside from rooted devices)?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski What is the problem now? It is apparently possible on non rooted devices according to Reddit. Conny has verified it.

Comment: I reopened your question however you edited it and it's now significantly different from its former form. In future do not edit the question that much but ask new one instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats --reset
```

That will reset the battery stats.
Its files are found in /data/system, but those are not accessable unless you are rooted.

Comment: source: https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/i1sxem/help_clear_battery_stats/